# JQuery .click not working as I expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick

I have a question about the .click function in Jquery. I have this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var divTest = $('<div></div>');
    divTest.text("My Div " + i);
    divTest.click(function() {
        alert("Alert: Div " + i);
    });
    $('#myTest').append(divTest);
}​
```

I expected to add five divs to the "myTest" element and for each div the onclick function would show an alert with the corresponding div number.

The divs were added properly, but when I click on the divs I always get the alert with the text: `"Alert: Div 5"`. Why? What I have to change to generate the behavior that I'm expecting?

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BKFGm/2/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case you should use [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1249581):

```
(function(i) {
    divTest.click(function() {
        alert("Div: " + i);
    });
})(i);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BKFGm/4/

---

Another option is to pass `i` in the [`eventData`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) map:

```
divTest.click({ i: i }, function(e) {
    alert("Div: " + e.data.i);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BKFGm/11/

Comment: Note that you're creating a new function object for each iteration, which may cause performance issues when there is a large number of iterations. A declared function would provide better performance in that case.

Comment: OH I see. I didn´t know this term. Thanks for your time! I'll accept as soon as possible.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Agreed with your first note. Maybe `eventData` is a good alternative for such cases.

Answer (score 5):

Once again, a classic case of closures. `i` keeps getting incremented, whereas you want to anchor it in the `click` event. Try this:

```
for( i=0; i<5; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    // your code that depends on `i` here
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: OH I see. I didn´t know this term. Thanks for your time! Its working now =D

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue. Also, it's a very commonly asked question here.

The simple fix:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     var divTest = $('<div></div>')
         divTest .text("My Div " + i);

    (function(index){
        divTest .click(function () {
             alert("Div: " + index);
                    });
    })(i);

        $('#myTest').append(divTest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `Alert` happens, the variable `i` is already set to `5`.

Answer (score 0):

`.click` works in a different scope than your cycle and it is `undefined` when your click handler is executed, unless you have an other i variable on the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

### You can also try this

```
$(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        var divTest = $('<div/>', {
            'text':"My Div " + i,
            'click':(function(i){
                return function(){
                    alert("Div: " + i);
                }
            })(i)
        });
        $('#myTest').append(divTest);
    }
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BKFGm/12/).